# Can't load icon from resources using LoadIcon WINAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Why this line of code does not work in visual c++

```
_icon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL) ,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
```

I checked the rc file and resource.h and the icon definition is there
The rc file

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "resources\\close.ico"
```

resource.h

```
#define IDI_ICON1                       101
```

I'm using this code inside a static lib so the HINSTANCE is the same as the of exe right ?
but I always get ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND error.

Comment: Did you include the static library's .res file?

Comment: I guess not, how should do that ?

Comment: With Additional dependencies in the Linker options. Note that resource ID's in the static library may conflict with ID's defined in your project's resource.h

Comment: thanks man it works, you should put it as an answer

Comment: It's a mistake to use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` here. For a start you can achieve the same by passing `NULL`. You'd know that if you read the documentation carefully. But secondly, consider what happens if you compile your code into a DLL. Always use the module handle of the module that contains the code.

Comment: I read it, it says that I must use NULL for standard icon

Comment: You aren't loading a standard icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the static library's .res file using additional dependencies in the Linker options. Note that resource ID's in the static library may conflict with ID's defined in your project's resource.h